# iPhone app UI element

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

http://culturedcode.com/things/

do you guys know what UI element they used for their the top menu (home, car, phone...), the "A magical tag bar"? or is it a custom made UI? If so how do I make one that look like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular old UIToolbar looks rather like that actually, but larger.  Actually thats a good thing, finger fatness being accounted for.  As for buttons which have that 'pressed' look/are modal, I don't *think* I've seen one on the app store yet, but they should be fairly easy to make by subclassing UIButton, overriding the drawing method, rendering the background, or not, as a three part image, depending on its modal state, then just calling the standard UIButton drawing implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You linked to the Mac version of the Things, which does indeed have such a UI element. But the [iPhone version](http://culturedcode.com/things/iphone/), which you seem to be interested in, does not have any such control. That specific control isn't included in the iPhone SDK. The closest equivalent is [UISegmentedControl](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html).

Comment: does the iPad have something similar? I think I have seem something like it.